# Как правильно написать данное предложение?

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

Правильно ли написано: "Вам пытаешься помочь а вам лишь бы кого-то пообсуждать"?

Answer (score 1):

**Вам пытаешься помочь, а вам лишь бы кого-то пообсуждать.**

Примечания.
Немного коряво, но допустимо в разговорном стиле.
Вопрос "Как правильно написать без ошибок?" содержит плеоназм: "правильно" и "без ошибок" означает одно и то же. В слове *пытаешься* пропущены буквы. Есть и другие ошибки в самом вопросе. Я его отредактировал.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь правильнее "пыта**ются**", поскольку "пытаешься" не сочетается с "вам": во втором лице это всегда приглашение *поставить себя на место говорящего*, и в результате выходит, что человеку предлагается мысленно помогать самому себе. Чтобы с выражением во втором лице сохранить желаемый смысл, нужно объект помощи перевести в третье (а он, а ему...):

> Пыта**ешься** **ему** помочь, а **ему** лишь бы кого-то пообсуждать.

Если же сохранить в исходном предложении "вам", то в третье лицо говорящий может поставить себя (это приглашение посмотреть на обоих со стороны, а не с места говорящего):

> **Вам** пыта**ются** помочь, а **вам** лишь бы кого-то пообсуждать.

Comment: Тут ради правильности немного затуманен смысл. "Пытаешься помочь" воспринимается как "Я пытаюсь помочь", а "Пытаются помочь" можно понять и как "Я пытаюсь помочь", и как "Мы пытаемся помочь", и как "Некие люди пытаются помочь".

Answer (score 0):

После редактирования:

**Вам пытаешься помочь, а для Вас важнее кого-нибудь пообсуждать.**

**Пояснение:**

1)  Убираем повтор ***Вам***. Причем это не просто повтор, а нежелательное совпадение формы для субъекта и объекта: в первом случае объект (помочь ВАМ), во втором случае субъект (Вам важно/интересно).

2) Местоимение ***кого-нибудь*** со значением "безразично кто" здесь больше подходит.  Основное значение местоимения ***кого-то*** —  неизвестное, но конкретное лицо (некто).

**КТО-НИБУДЬ**, кого-нибудь, кому-нибудь, кого-нибудь, кем-нибудь, о ком-нибудь; местоим. сущ. Какой-л. человек, безразлично кто.

**КТО-ТО**, местоим. сущ. 1. Неизвестно какой человек; некто. Кто-то тебе звонил утром.  2. Какой-л. человек, безразлично кто; кто-нибудь. Кто-то должен взять на себя ответственность.